# Get value for only one JSON variable

Tags: python, json, parsing, request

I want to get the value for [`last`](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd/) with Python, using `requests` and `json`. I have this:

```
import requests
import json

res = requests.get('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd/')
print res.json['last']
```

But it showed me this:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

It's working to get all JSON code with `res.json()` but I want only the value from `'last'`.

Comment: Did you mean `res.json()['last']` (note parentheses)? You're trying to index into the method, not the JSON data it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.json()` will parse the responses json object, which you need to do, to access any value of it. So to access the value `last`, you need to do: `res.json()['last']`